# How can I find out if I am admissible to the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, canadian-citizens, refugees

I am currently a Canadian citizen, I got my citizenship in 2015.

In 1998 I entered the US under tourist Visa Program B2 Visa, I was an Algerian citizen at that time. 
In 2000 I got married to a US citizen and I applied for my Green Card, I was denied in October 2001 and my wife told immigration officer that I married to get my green card. My application got denied and I was given removal proceeding but never been contacted again my Immigration. In 2003 I applied for asylum based on sexual orientation and I was granted to stay in USA. In 2006 I left US and came to Canada. How can I check if I can travel back to US without facing problems?

Comment: After you were granted asylum, did you apply for permanent residency? If you maintained status until you left the USA, you don’t have a problem with inadmissibility. Being granted asylum **cured** your previous sham marriage issue.

Comment: @user56513 is there any chance you could post that as an answer with a reference?

Comment: Under section 204(c) of the INA, an alien who for whom it is determined has previously sought status based on a fraudulent marriage (whether or not he or she obtained such status) is precluded from having an immigrant visa petition under section 204(b) approved on his or her behalf. This covers **family-sponsored and employment-based immigrant visa petitions**.

Comment: Even where the section 204(c) bar applies, it only applies to principal beneficiaries of family- and employment-based immigrant visa petitions. **All other forms of relief and benefits are not barred by section 204(c**). For example, **an applicant for asylum or refugee adjustment would be eligible for a section 209(c) waiver**

Comment: Interesting question.  So, it's not as simple as the Canadian citizenship wiping the slate clean.

Comment: To answer your question we need to know, after your asylum was approved did you apply for permanent residency **and** during your application did you apply for and were granted a 209(c) waiver? Were you ultimately approved for permanent residence? If you were not because you were not granted the waiver, it means you still have misrepresentation/fraud on your record and hence you are inadmissible to the USA despite your Canadian citizenship.

Comment: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Laws/Memoranda/Static_Files_Memoranda/Archives%201998-2008/2005/209cadjwvr103105.pdf

Comment: Ultimately an easy and stress free method to definitely know you’re inadmissible is to try entering the USA **by road**. If you’re inadmissible they’ll turn you around and you just drive back into Canada 

Comment: Please enter answers into the answer field.

Comment: How do you intend to enter the USA and with what visa? A tourist visa? Asylum? You do not really specify....You can always apply for a tourist visa, easily, and see the outcome?

Answer (score 5):

Normally when you are residing in the US with conditional status, you can travel freely, but it is advised that you notify the USCIS of your travel plans prior.  Your case is definitely exceptional given your prior history.  You should consult a good immigration attorney, if you are worried rather than just look for advice on the internet.  They will be able to explain the true nature of your status.